# Comparing encoders to same input of differnt output size

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, encoding, vector-space-models, encoder

Let's say I have an input `s1` and I pass it to two encoders `e1` and `e2`. They output encodings of size `s1` and `s2`, where their length are not equal, lets say `len(s1) = k*len(s2)`. Is it possible to somehow compare which encoder is better out of the two ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encoders "encode" your high dimensionality input into a lower dimensional space. One way to compare different encoders is to use such representation for building the same model (say a NN with a fixed amount of layers) and to see which one is performing best or if the performance loss for the lower dimensionality is acceptable. A downside of that stand on the training procedure that advantage one representation instead of another. Think for example as having very few data points and to compare a big encoder with a small one: probably the small one will be better because it won't overfit.

You can also take this concept to the extreme and use those representations as inputs to a linear/logistic regression: in this way the chances of overfitting are very low and the better representation for the linear scenario will result in higher performances.